# First line of an auto genrated file is blank

Tags: php, file

I am generating a temporary file via PHP and forcing it to be downloaded using this code:

```
$liste = "this is a sample text to be displayed in the file"
$filename = "temp_code.txt";
header ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"' );
echo $liste;
```

The problem here is that the first line is a blank line and the output starts in the second line. 
this is the output of this script:

```
1 . 
2 .  this is a sample text to be displayed in the file
```

What I need to do is to avoid generating this first line.

Comment: You used almost pseudo-code in your question. How are we expected to find your superfluous line? The code also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: With this code your file stores only one line.

Comment: You might have an empty line in your php file. Make sure your <??> tags are the first and last lines.

Comment: The problem here is not in the query itself. I even tried a file generation with just echo "hello world" and the problem percists.

Comment: How exactly are you saving this file and confirming its content?

Comment: I am not saving it, I just _force_ it to be downloaded. no file is saved in the server.

Comment: And how are you saving it *in the browser and confirm its content*? Just a regular browser file download? What program do you use to open it? Have you tried using any lower-level tools to confirm the raw file's content?

Comment: by doing so when I simply access to this file (let's call it download.php and what is written above is every thing in this file) via the browser and a file download is triggered automatically. I am using this file as an input for another "black box" software.  It causes errors here because the output (as I shown already). When i open it using Notepad++ the result is a blank line before the content of '$line' is inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is by using an array like this.

```
$foo = array();
while($a = mysql...)
{
  $foo[] = $a['key'];
}
//your headers
echo implode(PHP_EOL,$foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line disappeared when I deleted a new line made using `enter key` after closing the `?>` of PHP or by simply deleting the `?>`