# I am trying write file with php and download it. Always first line appears in blank and that is wrong

Tags: php, xml, file, fwrite, file-put-contents

I am generating a file similar to xml.

When I have all string i try write and download it on fly.

The problem begins when I open the file: first line is blank and plain text begins in the second line. I have tested with fwrite, fput, and file_put_contents().... but......

I havn't been able to solve the problem...

This is the piece of code:

```
function dw($str, $name){
        $handle = fopen($name.'.fmt', "w");
        fwrite($handle, utf8_encode($str));
        fclose($handle);
        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($name.'.fmt'));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name.'.fmt'));
        readfile($name.'.fmt');
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First line of an auto genrated file is blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850629/first-line-of-an-auto-genrated-file-is-blank)

Comment: Isn't the same. I tested this way but that isn't a solution

Comment: Try with: $handle = fopen($name.'.fmt', "wb"); // or replacing utf8_encode for utf8_decode // or removing 'exit;' at bottom.

Comment: It isn't work. I have tried all three options and problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (perhaps someone needs this answer):

```
    $handle = fopen($name.'.fmt', "wb");
    rewind($handle);
    fwrite($handle, $new_dom->saveXML());
    fclose($handle);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($name.'.fmt'));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name.'.fmt'));
    ob_clean();
    readfile($name.'.fmt');
```